# Visual Studio '15' preview opening Work Items in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, team-explorer, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio '15' preview Microsoft introduce that Work Items (Bugs, Tasks, ....) isn't opened in Visual Studio but Visual Studio opens it in default web browser. In "What's new list" Microsoft says that if user uses older version of TFS, Visual Studio opens Work Items by old way.

My question is that is there any way force Visual Studio to opens Work Items in VS from any version of TFS? I am using Visual Studio Online and can't choose TFS version.

Comment: Not sure what you man with your last comment of not being able to choose your TFS version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the preview you can set your preferred way of opening work items using the settings available at `Tools -> Options -> Work Items`.

Comment: In addition, more information now available here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/22/work-items-now-open-in-the-web-from-visual-studio-15/

Answer (score 2):

No, new work item customization options such as the recently introduced checkbox features, as well as the new work item form layouts that were introduced in Visual Studio Team Services are not available in the work item controls available in the current release of Visual Studio's Controls library.

To ensure compatibility with the new process customization capabilities, new controls and the new Work item form options, Visual Studio will open work items in the browser.